# Competitor asking for me to sell my free product

Tags: sales

Ok, so another person has a paid product and I have produced a product that is very similar and nearly as good as the paid product. The creator of the paid product has personally messaged me asking for me not to release my product for free and instead I should charge money for it. I believe he is asking me this because he is afraid I will effect his sales. So my question is, should I go with what he is saying and sell the product because if I released for free I would effect his sales? I don't really know I just thought I'd ask and see what I should do and see if this has happened to anyone else before.
(Btw, the 'product' mentioned above is a form of 'software', I don't feel it is necessary to go any more in detail)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's a question about *business*, not a question about *the workplace*.  I don't know if there's another SE site where it would be on-topic (doesn't seem like it fits Freelancing either), sorry.

Comment: Sell it to him/her or do whatever you want. I upset and put 100's of cowboys who made a good living doing substandard rubbish with no qualifications out of work by releasing free software that did their job better than they did, They tried to get it banned, they complained to AG's office and even to the king who called me to come and explain myself. I couldn't care less. But if they'd offered to make me rich by buying it, that might have been different ;-)

Comment: Ask him the rate at which he wants you to sell your product, then sell it to him at that rate. Problem solved.

Comment: Remind him that price parity could also be achieved if he changes his price to match yours.

Comment: If you were to sell it, are you prepared to put in lots of work to made your hobby a business? Documentation, including help files, slick GUI, new features/feature requests, fast turn round on bug fixing, etc, etc? Like most people, I will put up with "rough & ready" if it is free & mostly gets the job done. That changes when I have to pay for the software.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a lot of good reasons I can think of to opt to monetize a product you've created, but "because my competitor asked me to" isn't one of them.